# Kafka timeout exception whenever kubernetes instances scale up or on new deployment

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kubernetes, apache-kafka

Seeing timeout exception in logs whenever i do new deployment in kubernetes or while scaling up or down the number of instances.

I have tried to handle graceful shutdown through kubernetes by setting the preStop and terminationGracePeriodSeconds but still it does not help

```
lifecycle:
        preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh","-c","sleep 10"]
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 100
```

have also tried by setting the timeout for kafka

```
request.timeout.ms: 10000
```

Still getting timeout exception
`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: fetchMetadata`